# Gnome-shell hide "Dock"?

Tags: gnome, docky, dock

I use Docky in Gnome-Shell,

Hence I don't need the gnome-shell dock.
Is there a way to disable (or at least hide) the gnome-shell dock?

I know I could set the width in whichever theme's CSS file I use to 0px, but that requires me to edit every theme I use.. every time it is updated (all my themes come from a PPA).

Perhaps there is an extension for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found an extension that does exactly that:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/79/hide-dash/